# Finding the loop invariant for Array Reversal

Tags: correctness-proof, first-order-logic, loop-invariants

I've been assigned to find the loop invariant for the following code:

```
i=0;
j=n-1;
while(i < n/2){
    l = A[i];
    r = A[j];
    A[j] = l;
    A[i] = r;
    j = j-1;
    i = i+1;
}
```

I understand the code function (reverses array), the guard (`i < n/2`), and I can find different invariants (e.g. `i+j = n-1`), but I'm stuck finding anything useful that relates the precondition:

```
A[0], A[1] ... A[n-2], A[n-1]
```

to the postcondition:

```
A[n-1], A[n-2] ... A[1], A[0]
```

Can anyone help with this problem, or even generally how to find useful invariants for loops that operate on arrays?

Comment: Those aren't preconditions/postconditions.  What reading and study have you done?  What *do* you understand about loop invariants, and what progress have you made?  Can you write down any proposition that will be true on every iteration of the loop, anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invariant will express that we have performed a partial reversal, i.e. the array zones `A[0..i[` and `A[n-i..n[` have been swapped the intended way, while the middle is unchanged.

So, if you denote the *initial* content of the array as `Z`, the invariant is like

```
Forall k: k < i => A[k] = Z[n-k] and n/2 > k ≥ i => A[k] = Z[k]
```

(Caution: off-by-one errors are possible, I didn't check.)